# Case expression is not working in Values which 0.02

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a query which has value Like this *0.02* and so on...

Note:- When I tried to add case expression to `convert` like this

```
>= 0.00 and <= 0.049 then 1 Star
```

it's giving me null values

```
  ,case 
    when cast([main_stars_score] as integer) >=0.05 
     and cast([main_stars_score] as integer) <= 1 
       then  N'1 نجم'
    when cast([main_stars_score] as integer) > 0.01 
    and  cast([main_stars_score] as integer) <=0.049 
       then  N'0 نجم'
```

**Output:-**
must come 1 star 
and below 0.049 then come 0 star

Comment: Integer is a whole number, i.e. 0, 1, 2, etc. It makes no sense to compare it with `>=0.05` and `<= 1`, you could just as well write `= 1`, because the only integer greater or equal 0.05 and less or equal 1 is 1. And there exists no integer greater 0.01 but less or equal 0.049. So, why do you cast to integer at all?

Comment: What data type is main_stars_score? Which value do you want in case of 0.0491? It looks like you merely want `case when main_stars_score >= 0.05 then  N'1 نجم' else N'0 نجم' end`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally your `main_stars_score` should be either numeric or floating point type.  If it really be floating point *text*, then you should be casting to a numeric type:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN CAST([main_stars_score] AS NUMERIC(10,2)) BETWEEN 0.05 AND 1.0
         THEN N'1 نجم'
         WHEN CAST([main_stars_score] AS NUMERIC(10,2)) BETWEEN 0.01 AND 0.049
         THEN N'0 نجم' END AS label
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: The "short case" syntax only allows equality comparison `case <expression> when between ....` is invalid